# Reshape (Melt?) data whilst combining columns with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01/01/2021','08/01/2021'],
                  'a_score':[7,3],
                  'b_score':[2,4],
                  'a':['north','south'],
                  'b':['south','north']})

Date        a_score b_score a       b
01/01/2021  7       2       north   south
08/01/2021  3       4       south   north
```

How can I best reshape this to stack the data in columns a and b together and also stack a_score and b_score together?  The desired output looks like this:

```
Date        Region  score   score_against
01/01/2021  north   7       2
01/01/2021  south   2       7
08/01/2021  north   4       3
08/01/2021  south   3       4
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can take the inner numpy array and manipulate it to get the required result:

```
import numpy as np
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((df.values,df.values[:, [0,2, 1, 4,3]]))[:, :-1], columns = ['Date', 'score', 'score_against', 'Region'])
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
         Date score score_against Region
0  01/01/2021     7             2  north
1  08/01/2021     3             4  south
2  01/01/2021     2             7  south
3  08/01/2021     4             3  north
```

##### Explanation:

```
np.vstack((df.values,df.values[:, [0,2, 1, 4,3]]))[:, :-1]
```

Take the inner numpy array (df.values) swap the columns and then vertically stack it with the original numpy array:

```
array([['01/01/2021', 7, 2, 'north'],
       ['08/01/2021', 3, 4, 'south'],
       ['01/01/2021', 2, 7, 'south'],
       ['08/01/2021', 4, 3, 'north']], dtype=object)
```

Now, you can use the above `array` to create a new dataframe.

###### NOTE:

If required -> sort via Date column.

```
new_df = new_df.sort_values('Date')
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
         Date score score_against Region
0  01/01/2021     7             2  north
2  01/01/2021     2             7  south
1  08/01/2021     3             4  south
3  08/01/2021     4             3  north
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  Very helpful simple code and clearly explained.